# Gravity Form on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I am trying to pull dynamic form id to create a dropdown for the end-user. This I have done here.

Now, I'd like to pass that id so that a different form shows up based on selection as shown below:

```
<form class="ui form">
    <select name="select" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
           <?php $myforms = RGFormsModel::get_forms(); foreach ($myforms as $form) { ?> 
             <option name="select" value="<?php echo $form->id ?>"> <?php echo $form->title ?> </option>                
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
<?php echo gravity_form($form, true, true, false, '', true, 1); ?>
```

Comment: You could pass the form ID as a URL parameter and write a function to integrate that into the standard gravity form embed code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still struggling a bit with this. I added jQuery to identify selected option-value. I just don't know how to pass to a PHP variable?: <script>
 (function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function () {   
  $("select#select").change(function(){
   var form = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  });  
 });    
 })(jQuery);
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I might do to make a shortcode for gravity forms that pulls the ID from the URL parameter.

```
function return_gform_embed(){
  $form_id = $_GET["form_id"];
  return do_shortcode('[gravityform id="'.$form_id.'" title="false" description="false"]');
}

add_shortcode('form-url', 'return_gform_embed');
```

You'd add the shortcode `[form-url]` to the page where you'd like the form to display.

So now the URL with `?form_id=6` would load the gravity form with id 6. I didn't test the whole javascript aspect but assuming you can change the URL and force a reload things should work out ok.

Comment: Thank you. It works great; however, I have the form in a modal and the param is dying on refresh. I'll keep working at it. It was very kind of you taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing if it helps someone else out there:

```
<form class="ui form">          
    <select name="select" id="select" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <?php
            function return_gform_embed(){
                 $form_id = $_GET["form_id"];
                 return do_shortcode('[gravityform id="'. $form_id .'" title="false" description="false"]');
        }
            add_shortcode('form-url', 'return_gform_embed');            
        ?>
        <?php $myforms = RGFormsModel::get_forms(); foreach ($myforms as $form) { ?>
            <option value="/prevention/sessions/?form_id=<?php echo $form->id ?>"> <?php echo $form->title ?> </option>
        <?php } ?>      
    </select>
</form>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[form-url]') ?>
```